# ionic 2 dependency injection between page and modal

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection, ionic2

I am passing data to my modal from my class like below.When I trigger `ChangeCheck()` function  inside modal view, `checkin` is not changing when I go back to `MyMap` class.Do you know How can I chance it's value from my modal.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-my-map',
  templateUrl: 'my-map.html',
  providers:[CommonVariables]
})

export class MyMap {
  checkin:boolean=false;

constructor(public commonvar:CommonVariables,public modalCtrl: 

ModalController,
public nav:NavController,public alertCtrl:AlertController) {
}

public openBasicModal() {//this functions is triggered once I click the button to open my Modal

    let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalContentPage,{'myParam':this.checkin});
    myModal.present();
  }

}

@Component({//this is my modal template
  templateUrl:'my-modal.html',
})
export class ModalContentPage {//my modal class
    checkin:boolean;
    constructor(public alertCtrl:AlertController,
    public viewCtrl: ViewController,
    params: NavParams,
    public commonvar:CommonVariables
  ) {
     this.checkin = params.get('myParam');//I am getting this value from MyClass .

  }
      ChangeCheck ( ) {//I trigger this function.but when I close the my modal, it doesn't change the checkin which inside `MyClass`.
                this.checkin = !this.checkin;
}

    dismiss() {
       this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your also missing `public` for your params

```
public params: NavParams
```

To your **Question** : Of cource it will not change, you have to send it back.

Add this to your **ModalController** class

```
 let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalContentPage,{'myParam':this.checkin});

  myModal.onDidDismiss(data => {
     console.log(data);
   });
        myModal.present();
```

Then add this in your **ModalContentPage** class

```
    dismiss() {
   let data = { 'checkin': this.checkin };
   this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
    }
```

Comment: sorry I typed it false by mistake.the real code is true.let me correct it.